# How to solve ArgumentError using rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to do edit profile in my app.When i inserted the new setting and updating it it is giving me the below error.

Error:

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
Rails.root: C:/Site/library_management1

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/homes_controller.rb:148:in `updatedata'
```

My codes are as follows

## views/homes/userprofile.html.erb

```
<% if current_user %>
<div class="totaldiv">
  <div class="navdiv"><span>STUDENT INFORMATION</span><span>Logged in as <%= current_user.email %></span></div>
  <div class="wrapper">
  <div id="leftsidebtn">
 <ul>
  <li><a href="/homes/issuebooks">Book issue</a></li>
   <li><a href="/homes/availablebooks">Books Available</a></li>
   <li><a href="/homes/magazines?user_id=<%= current_user.id %>">Magazines Purchase</a></li>
   <li><a href="/homes/newspaper">Newspaper Purchase</a></li>
   <li><a href="/homes/userprofile">Profile settings</a></li>
   <li><a href="/homes/blog">My Blog</a></li>
<li><a href="/sessions/removeuser">Log Out</a></li>
 </ul>  
</div>
  </div>
  <div class="restdiv" id="ex3" >
<center>
  <div class="edit-profile"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btnShowModal" >Edit Your Profile</button></div>
  <div id="output"></div>

<div id="overlay" class="web_dialog_overlay"></div>
<div id="dialog" class="web_dialog">
<div class="edit-firstdiv">
  <div class="web_dialog_title align_right">
            <a href="#" id="btnClose">Close</a>
  </div>
  <%= form_for :users,:url => {:action => 'updatedata',:id => params[:id] } do |f| %>
  <% if @users.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@users.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @users.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<div class="edit-firstname">
<label for="first_name">First Name</label>
<%= f.text_field :first_name,:id => 'first_name',:value => @users.first_name %>
</div>
<div class="edit-lastname">
<label for="last_name">Last Name</label>
<%= f.text_field :last_name,:id => 'first_name',:value => @users.last_name %>
</div>
<div class="edit-emailid">
<label for="emailid">Emailid</label>
<%= f.email_field :email,:id => 'first_name',:value => @users.email %>
</div>
<div class="edit-password">
<label for="password">Password</label>
<%= f.password_field :password,:id => 'first_name',:value => @users.password %>
</div>
<div class="edit-confirm">
<label for="Address">Password again</label>
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation,:id => 'first_name' %>
</div>
<div class="edit-telephone">
<label for="phone">Phone no</label>
<%= f.telephone_field :tel_no,:id => 'first_name',:value => @users.tel_no %>
</div>
<div class="edit-address">
<label for="Address">Address</label>
<%= f.text_area :address,:class => 'address_text',:value => @users.address %>
<textarea id="first_name"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="edit-submit">
  <%= f.submit 'Update Data',:class => 'btn btn-success' %>
</div>
</div>
<% end %>
  </div>
</center>
  </div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

## controller/homes_controller.rb

```
class HomesController < ApplicationController
     before_filter :authenticate_admin!,only: [:admin]
    def index

    end
    def admin

    end
    def managebooks
        @books=Book.new
        if params[:id]
            @books=Book.find(params[:id])
            @book=Book.all
        end
    end
    def savebooks
        @books=Book.new(params[:books])
        if @books.save
            flash[:notice]="Data has submitted successfully"
            flash[:color]="valid"
            redirect_to :action => 'managebooks',:id => @books.id
        else
            flash[:notice]="Data couldnot submitted successfully"
            flash[:color]="invalid"
            render 'managebooks'
        end
    end
    def remove
        @books=Book.find(params[:id])
        @books.destroy
    end
    def books

    end
    def showbooks
        @books=Book.all
    end
    def searchbooks
        @books=Book.all
    end
    def member
        @users=User.new
    end
    def registration
        @users=User.new
    end
    def savedata
        @users=User.new(params[:users])
        if @users.save
            flash[:notice]="Data has submitted successfully"
            flash[:color]="valid"
            redirect_to :action => 'member'
        else
            flash[:notice]="Data could not submitted successfully"
            flash[:color]="invalid"
            render 'registration'
        end
    end
    def issuebooks
        @issues=Issue.new
    end
    def savedissuebooks
        @issues=Issue.new(params[:issues])
        if @issues.save
            flash[:notice]="information has saved successfully"
            flash[:color]="valid"
            redirect_to :action => 'member'
        else
            flash[:notice]="Data couldnot saved"
            flash[:color]="invalid"
            render 'issuebooks'
        end
    end
    def availablebooks

        @books=Book.all
    end
    def userissues
        @issues=Issue.all
    end
    def magazine
        @magazines=Magazine.new
    end
    def savemagazines
        @users=User.find(params[:id])
        @magazines=Magazine.new(params[:magazines])
        @magazines.user_id=@users.id
        if @magazines.save
            flash[:notice]="Data submitted successfully"
            flash[:color]="valid"
            redirect_to :action => "member"
        else
            flash[:notice]="Data could not saved"
            flash[:color]="invalid"
            render 'magazines'
        end
    end
    def magazineissue
        @magazines=Magazine.all
        @users=User.find @magazines.first.user_id
    end
    def blog
        @blogs=Blog.new
    end
    def savecomments
        @users=User.find(params[:id])
        @blogs=Blog.new(params[:blogs])
        @blogs.user_id=@users.id
        if @blogs.save
            flash[:notice]="Comment has been posted successfully"
            flash[:color]="valid"
            redirect_to :action => "showcomment"
        else
            flash[:notice]="Comment could not saved"
            flash[:color]="invalid"
            render 'blog'
        end
    end
    def showcomment
        @blogs=Blog.all
    end
    def newspaper
        @newspapers=Newspaper.new
    end
    def savenewspaper
        @users=User.find(params[:id])
        @newspapers=Newspaper.new(params[:newspapers])
        @newspapers.user_id=@users.id
        if @newspapers.save
            flash[:notice]="newspaper data saved successfully"
            flash[:color]="valid"
            redirect_to :action => "member"
        else
            flash[:alert]="Data could not saved successfully"
            flash[:color]="invalid"
            render 'newspaper'
        end
    end
    def adminnewspaperissue
        @newspapers=Newspaper.all
        @users=User.find @newspapers.first.user_id
    end
    def userprofile
        @users=User.find(params[:id])
    end
    def updatedata
        @users=User.find(params[:id])
        if @users.update_attributes(params(:users))
            flash[:notice]="User Data has updated"
            flash[:color]="valid"
            redirect_to :action => 'member'
        else
            flash[:alert]="Data could not updated"
            flash[:color]="invalid"
            render 'userprofile'
        end
    end
end
```

Please check my code and let me to know where i did mistake and what should be the solution.

Comment: Which line is 148th?

Comment: Marek The 148th line is if @users.update_attributes(params(:users))

Answer (score 1):

When debugging argument errors you have two possible options:

1. You passed to many or to few arguments to a function.
2. You made a typo that is confusing things.

The first thing to do is look at the stack trace provided. It will show you were to look. Most likely the error is on the line given in the trace or the line directly above it for some typos. In your case it says:

app/controllers/homes_controller.rb:148:in `updatedata'

This tells you to look in:

controller: homes_controller.rb

action: updatedata

exact line number: 148

Your code editor should have a way to show you line numbers and/or jump to a specific line number. If you look carefully at that location you will see a case where you are using () instead of []. I suspect that is confusing the system and causing the argument error.

Also, from a rails coding standard point of view, you should break that controller into multiple controllers. In general you should only have index, new, create, edit, update and delete actions in your controller. If you find yourself making many custom named actions it is a sign you need another controller.

Comment: Ok Rose now got it and it solved.But data is not updating while executing updatedata method.

Answer (score 0):

params is a hash, so you have to edit your line 148 to:

`if @users.update_attributes(params[:users])`